# Django Error when trying to post to endpoint of unmanaged model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest framework, and trying to create an endpoint for creating some object, which doesn't suppose to be saved in DB (managed=false).
I want to get 'JSONApi' response, so I understood I should create a model and a serializer for it.

This is the classView:

```
class OssObjectsViewSet(AuthenticatedCreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
serializer_class = OssObjectSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    m = OssObject()

    return [m]
```

this is the model:

```
class OssObject(models.Model):
class Meta:
    managed = False

class JSONAPIMeta:
    resource_name = "oss_objects"

id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)

@property
def urn(self):
    return 'yyy'
```

That's the serializer:

```
class OssObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

class Meta:
    model = OssObject
    fields = ['id', 'urn']
```

When sending Post request to the endpoint, I'm getting

```
{"data": {}, "message": "('relation \"submittals_ossobject\" does not exist\\nLINE 1: INSERT INTO \"submittals_ossobject\" (\"id\") VALUES (\\'81400b5b-...\\n ^\\n',)", "error_id": "8b9a3352-da41-4dd3-be09-5e63602aef46", "code": 10001}
```

When creating the classView with 'AuthenticatedListModelMixin' and send 'Get' request- it works fine.

Comment: did you get this working? I'm considering instantiating un-managed models to generate my API.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't use it at the end